# Please help: Users unable to log in into my google app engine app

Tags: google-app-engine

I have an app. I tested and am able to log in successfully on two machines (Windows Vista 32bit & Windows 7 Enterprise 64 bit) using a variety of browsers, but on a third machine (Windows 7 64 bit) I am unable to login using any browser! There is no 500 error I am seeing.

I click on login -> am taken to google log in page -> I enter my credentials -> they pass and I am redirected to my site -> but then I don't see myself logged in => users.get_current_user() is returning None (?).

Comment: Have cookies been disabled on the "broken" machine?

Comment: This sounds like an issue with the machine in question, not with App Engine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By fluke, I noticed the system date on the 3rd machine was one day ahead. I corrected that, and now it works for the moment. Would be interested to know from appengine experts why this would create a problem.

This same issue was also manifesting itself as 401 unknown header while doing gdata docsclient requests.